# Pointer to Member Function in Class Composition

Tags: c++, function, class

I have two classes, `Foo` and `Bar`.  Class `Foo` contains an instance of class `Bar` called `b` and class `Bar` needs to access the member function `FooFunc` of class `Foo`.  Function `FooFunc` performs some arithmetic, but for now I just want to try to pass it but I can't seem to make the following MWE (named `scratch.cpp`) work:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo;  // forward declaration

class Bar
{
public:
  Bar() {}
  void BarFunc(double (Foo::*func)(double))
  {
    std::cout << "In BarFunc \n";
  }
};

class Foo  // must be declared after Bar, else incomplete type
{
public:
  Foo() {}
  Bar b;

  double FooFunc(double x)
  {
    return x + 1;
  }
  void CallBarFunc()
  {
    b.BarFunc(FooFunc);  // error occurs here
  }
};

int main()
{
  Foo f;
  f.CallBarFunc();
}
```

The error I get is

```
scratch.cpp:27:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘Bar::BarFunc(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
scratch.cpp:27:22: note: candidate is:
scratch.cpp:9:8: note: void Bar::BarFunc(double (Foo::*)(double))
scratch.cpp:9:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘double (Foo::*)(double)’
```

Comment: Do you *have* to use member function pointers? Can't you use templates (like all standard library functions) or [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)?

Answer (score 3):

Unlike non-member functions, which decay to a function pointer, non-`static` member functions don't decay to a pointer.

Instead of:

```
     b.BarFunc(FooFunc);
```

Use:

```
     b.BarFunc(&Foo::FooFunc);
```

Comment: @R Sahu Thanks, that seems to have fixed it.  I'm really curious why, though.

Comment: @R Sahu Also, would you know how I could call `func(2)` after the `std::cout << "In BarFunc \n";`? I get a `error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘func (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* func) (...)’` error.

Comment: @bcf you have to make a Foo object to call it on. Remember that `&Foo::FooFunc` just identifies the function, there is no associated object.

Comment: @bcf, I don't know why that syntax was chosen by the language developers.